# Getting data from a file and inserting it into a list

Tags: python

I was trying to get data(a list) from a file and assign this list to my python script list.

I want to know how to do it without having to assign all varibles manually

```
Variables = [MPDev,WDev,DDev,LDev,PDev,MPAll,WAll,DAll,LAll,PAll,MPBlit,WBlit,DBlit,LBlit,PBlit,MPCour,WCour,DCour,LCour,PCour]
dataupdate = open("griddata.txt","r")
datalist = dataupdate.read()
#Inside the file is written:
#['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',']

var = 0
for e in Variables:
    e = datalist[var]
    var += 1
```

I got it working anyways but i would like to know a faster way to improve my skills. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get used to using data as a pandas dataframe.  It's easy to read, easy to write.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("griddata.txt", names = ['MPDev',
 'WDev',
 'DDev',
 'LDev',
 'PDev',
 'MPAll',
 'WAll',
 'DAll',
 'LAll',
 'PAll',
 'MPBlit',
 'WBlit',
 'DBlit',
 'LBlit',
 'PBlit',
 'MPCour',
 'WCour',
 'DCour',
 'LCour',
 'PCour']
)
```

Comment: I get a error using this code `TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns' `

Comment: Oops.  replace "columns" with "names"

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
Variables = [MPDev,WDev,DDev,LDev,PDev,MPAll,WAll,DAll,LAll,PAll,MPBlit,WBlit,DBlit,LBlit,PBlit,MPCour,WCour,DCour,LCour,PCour]  
dataupdate = open("tmp.txt","r")
datalist = ast.literal_eval(dataupdate.read())

#Inside the file is written:
#['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',']

for i in Variables:
    i=datalist[Variables.index(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using dictionary. 
`mydict={}
var = 0
for e in Variables:
    mydict[e]=datalist[var]
    var += 1`